# When a user sends a command in Discord, how can the arguments be separated by a character in-message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, bots, discord

So a user sends the message (just for example) `=rateM 8 | Led Zepplin | Immigrant Song` in Discord to rate a song from 1-10. What I want to do is make it so that the vertical bar character, |, separates the arguments of the command.

My code for the command is `if(command === "rateM") let [score, artist, song] = args };`.  What I want to do is make it so that I can define, for example, the argument `score` as being everything in between the command `=rateM` and the first vertical bar.  How can I do this?  Would I use `split();` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get rid of `rateM` by removing first 5 characters from user message,

```
let message = "rateM 8 | Led Zepplin | Immigrant Song" // user message

let argsString = message.substring(5);
```

Now split the string to make array with arguments,

```
lets args = argsString.split(" | ")
/*args[0] === 8
  args[1] === Led Zeppelin
  args[2] === Immigrant Song*/
```